# AngularJS: Tracing error

Tags: angularjs

Upgrading AngularJS from version `1.4.9` to latest version `1.6.7` I'm facing a lot of errors in chrome console like:

```
angular.js:14794 Error: [orderBy:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.7/orderBy/notarray?p0=%7B%7D
    at angular.js:88
    at angular.js:22657
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15645), <anonymous>:4:259)
    at angular.js:16752
    at m.$digest (angular.js:18351)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:18628)
    at angular.js:1958
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5097)
    at c (angular.js:1956)
    at Uc (angular.js:1976)
```

Dealing with a large code base, it seems pretty much hard to pinpoint the places causing these errors. How can I trace the root cause of such problems? Are there any browser plugins available?

Answer (score 1):

Use 'toArray:false' in your ng-repeat. This happens when filter or 
     Orderby is applied in ng-repeat, but on Object instead of array.

```
 <div ng-repeat="i in obj | toArray:false | filter:searchText">
```

Comment: 1- Yet if I have 400 instances of `orderBy`, I can not figure out which one is fed an object, instead of an array. I mean I still can pinpoint the file and line number, because error trace is not precise.
2- `toArray` is a filter and should be added to code base: https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter